# Setting Wordpress Post dates to 1914

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently working on a Blog that is covering events of World War one in "real time". To accomplish this i would to set the entry dates to 1914. Doing this in the Wordpress admin interface obviously doesn't do the trick. 
So now i'm wondering how to accomplish this. 
Option one: Adjust the template, but then i would have to actually modify a lot of code and have the problem all over again as soon as i change templates.
option two: modify wordpress' get_the_date function. 
Other options?

Comment: Why not? You can directly change it on the admin panel. Just edit the post.

Comment: It seems works on my machine.. 1900 year is also ok.

Answer (score 2):

UNIX time starts on January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT. See https://www.php.net/time

So setting your actual post date to a date before 1970 in WordPress - even it appears to work - won't work in the end. It has to do with UNIX, PHP constraints and not WordPress.

Various threads: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-post-before-december-31-1969?replies=12

Best thing to do is use a custom field to enter the ~1914 dates and call that custom field as the post date in your template files. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

Now, if you want to display posts sorted by date, the actual post date can still matter, though. So date the posts for the same `day` in 1914, and your posts will still be arranged by date, ascending or descending. WordPress will sort the posts by day.

Or, you can also change the main loop to sort by custom field, but it seems to be an easier workaround to use the same `day` in 1914, and display the year by custom field.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the post date in the WordPress Admin Panel.

Just on the post editing menu.